# Which commits should I use when calculating DORA "Lead time" metric?

Tags: git, devops

As per the "Accelerate State of DevOps 2019" (you can download it [here](https://www.devops-research.com/research.html)) they define lead time for changes as:

> how long does it take to go from code
> committed to code successfully running in production?

I wonder how should you calculate this when you have multiple commits because I see at two potential interpretations:

1. You calculate lead time for **all** commits (focus on how much
   WIP do you accumulate and how often you go live)
2. You calculate lead time **only** for the commits that go live (focus
   on how fast if your pipeline process to take one commit live).

If you are doing continuous deployment, there should be no difference between option A and B, but if you only deploy some of your commits then you would get different results.

Can someone clarify which is the intended way to calculate lead time please?
Thanks!

Comment: When you say "deploy some of your commits", are you saying that some commits simply never make it to production, or that you deploy batches of commits to production at once?

Comment: The latter, we don't deploy all of our commits, sometimes we make multiple commits before we roll-out to production. 
In other words, CI builds all commits and all commits can be promoted to production, but not all of them are promoted (only some, it's up to us as there's a manual step at the end of the pipeline)

Comment: Is there a branch or tag you use to denote code that goes to production?

Comment: Nope, there's no need to do such things as all code should be releasable to production. We develop trunk-based but we decide on-demand which commits are promoted to production.

Comment: So how do you know which commits went to production?

Comment: Also, why not calculate both metrics? You might just want to decide on one of the metrics and go with it. Maybe consult management about which metric they would find useful?

Comment: The answer should be in this official project: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fourkeys